# Is it practical to make an exe without it being flagged as false-positive for malware?

Tags: open-source

I made a small utility as a PowerShell script. It worked fine, but wasn't very practical when getting other people to run it who weren't familiar with PowerShell. I modified it to add a GUI using `System.Windows.Forms` and then used PS2EXE to turn it into an executable. Again, this worked fine - double click the exe, do what you need in the GUI. The problem with this is when other people download it, it gets flagged as potentially malware (it isn't, I promise, but it seems to be an issue with the files PS2EXE produces, they get commonly flagged). The suggested workaround is to sign it, but my initial research suggests code-signing certificates are expensive, I haven't seen one for less than $200 for a year - not practical for my use-case.

So my next option would be to rewrite it in another language that compiles natively. I assume for a Windows app C#.NET seems to be most common? But if I go this route, am I only going to have the same problem if I don't buy a code-signing certificate?

How do people make open-source executables without buying expensive code-signing certificates that don't get blocked as potential malware?

Comment: Can you directly invoke your PowerShell script from your Windows EXE, rather than making it an executable?

Comment: I think this is more of a stack overflow type of question being that it's a specific issue with a specific tool.

Comment: I'm not asking so much about the particular tools in my example, more if I go to the trouble of implementing it another (any other!) language/tech stack, am I still going to have the same problems with it being flagged as potential malware because it's not signed? What's the best ways to go about creating a Windows executable app without an expensive code-signing cert?

Comment: I would be tempted to say just create a "premium" version which is identical to the OSS version except its signed - simply charge for download (which doesn't typically violate OSS licenses) to recoup the cost of the cert - and explain on your site that's what your doing.

Comment: Consider using Windows Store to distribute your tools.